# On the condition $\frac{\sin x_1}{\sin(\alpha+x_2-x_1)} = \frac{\sin x_2}{\sin(\alpha+x_3-x_2)} = \cdots = \frac{\sin x_n}{\sin(\alpha+x_1-x_n)}$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, symmetric-functions

> If we have $$\frac{\sin x_1}{\sin(\alpha+x_2-x_1)} = \frac{\sin x_2}{\sin(\alpha+x_3-x_2)} = \cdots = \frac{\sin x_n}{\sin(\alpha+x_1-x_n)}.$$
>
> Here $0<x_i<\frac{\pi}{2} (i=1,2,\cdots,n), 0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$.
>
> Is $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n$ true? Prove it or give a counter example.

I think it is true, but can not prove it.

Comment: Where does this question comes from ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it likes a regular polygon with $n$ edge $A_1A_2A_3 \cdots A_n$, and there are some points on each edge, $B_1$ on $A_1A_2$, $B_2$ on $A_2A_3$, like so, and $A_1B_1=A_2B_2=\cdots$, we know $B_1B_2\cdots B_n$ is a regular polygon easily. now conversely, if we know $B_1B_2\cdots B_n$ is a regular polygon, and $A_1B_1=A_2B_2=\cdots$, is it means $A_1A_2A_3 \cdots A_n$ is a regular polygon? by sine theorem, I get that equations.

Comment: I think that the original question is simpler to solve (using for example complex numbers) than the question of proportionality of sines.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your attention. but for me, the difficulty is almost the same, although geometry is more intuitive.